# Blanking out records but when combo box option selected make filling them out compulsory

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm hoping someone may be able to help with this I have managed to get the basic's but I'm a bit stuck with the next stage.

Currently I have been able to grey out the required fields when the various options are selected from my combo box "Type" I have also been able to get the code to check my fields to make sure that something is entered into the non greying out fields.

However the part I am stuck on is that I am unable to make my "Type" combo box into a compulsory field and keep it greying out the other boxes.

And even one step further if possible when these boxes aren't greyed out I would like these to then also become compulsory

This is the code I currently have:

```vb
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If IsNull(DDI.Value) Then
MsgBox "You Must Enter a Number in DDI"
Cancel = True
DDI.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If

If IsNull(Extn.Value) Then
MsgBox "You Must Enter a Number in Extn"
Cancel = True
Extn.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If

If IsNull(Location.Value) Then
MsgBox "You Must Enter a Number in Location"
Cancel = True
Location.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If

If IsNull(Analogue.Value) Then
MsgBox "You Must Enter a Number in Analogue/Cisco"
Cancel = True
Analogue.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If

End Sub

Private Sub Type_AfterUpdate()

Select Case Me.Type.Value

Case Is = "Voice"
Me.StaffNumber.Enabled = True
Me.Firstname.Enabled = True
Me.Surname.Enabled = True
Me.UserCode.Enabled = True
Me.DeptCode.Enabled = True
Me.FaxLine.Enabled = False

Case Is = "Fax"
Me.StaffNumber.Enabled = False
Me.Firstname.Enabled = False
Me.Surname.Enabled = False
Me.UserCode.Enabled = False
Me.DeptCode.Enabled = False
Me.FaxLine.Enabled = True

Case Is = "Alarm"
Me.StaffNumber.Enabled = False
Me.Firstname.Enabled = False
Me.Surname.Enabled = False
Me.UserCode.Enabled = False
Me.DeptCode.Enabled = False
Me.FaxLine.Enabled = False

Case Is = "Lift"
Me.StaffNumber.Enabled = False
Me.Firstname.Enabled = False
Me.Surname.Enabled = False
Me.UserCode.Enabled = False
Me.DeptCode.Enabled = False
Me.FaxLine.Enabled = False

Case Is = "Hunt Group"
Me.StaffNumber.Enabled = False
Me.Firstname.Enabled = False
Me.Surname.Enabled = False
Me.UserCode.Enabled = False
Me.DeptCode.Enabled = False
Me.FaxLine.Enabled = False

End Select

End Sub
```

I have also attached a few images to try and better explain based on the drop down options:

Voice Option

[image]

Alarm Option

[image]

Comment: Please clarify... are you graying out the fields you want filled in?  And you want "Type" combo to be required? But what does 'and keep it greying out the other boxes' mean? When you select type, what does it not do that you need it to do? Once you get the 'required' color correct, you can spin thru all controls, looking for that property and check if filled in.

Comment: @Wayne G. Dunn the user must select one of the 4 options in the type box (so i need to make sure they have selected one or they get prompted to pick one) then if the user selects the option for voice in the type field all boxes become white and I need the user to fill them all in (with no gaps) so I want to make sure it all gets filled in or else they get prompted too go back and fill in. where as if the user selects Alarm they don't need to complete any of the information on the right hand side so it gets greyed out and they are able to proceed onto the next record

Comment: In your 'Form_BeforeUpdate', the first check should be to make sure 'Type' was selected. Then, like you have in 'Type_AfterUpdate', do the same 'CASE' and make sure the required fields are populated (those that are 'Enabled = True'). Does this help, or do you want the code?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn Thankyou! I will give this a shot and if I get stuck I'll let you know lol

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn the only issue I seem to have run into is when I have they greyed out and have the 'Enabled = False' my code doesn't seem to know how to respond to this, so I'm not sure if ive put my case statement in the correct place. In the example above I have put it just before the End Sub part. is this the correct place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to allow Null in any of those 6 controls when they are `Enabled`.

In `Form_BeforeUpdate`, create an array of those those control names, and loop through each item in the array.  If one of them is both `Enabled` and Null, notify the user and `Cancel` the update.

```vb
Dim astrControls As Variant
Dim varItem As Variant
astrControls = Split("StaffNumber,Firstname,Surname,UserCode,DeptCode,FaxLine", ",")
For Each varItem In astrControls
    With Me.Controls(varItem)
        If .Enabled And IsNull(.Value) Then
            MsgBox "value required in " & varItem
            .SetFocus
            Cancel = True
            Exit For
        End If
    End With
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to worry if the fields are grayed out (.Enabled = False) because a user can't enter anything if not enabled. Then you want to make sure the user enters something for all Enabled fields. The following is one way to use code inside the 'BeforeUpdate' event.

```
If Me.txtFldA.Enabled = True Then
    If Me.txtFldA.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "Missing value in FldA"
        Cancel = True
        Me.txtFldA.SetFocus
    End If
End If
```

If you were to have *many* text boxes to check, you could loop thru all controls on the form, check if the ControlType = acTextBox, then check if missing value. Since you would have the control name and the ControlSource, you could use those values in your display/check message and avoid writing code for every control.